# Show that $f(W_t)-\frac{1}{2} \int_0^t f''(W_s) \, ds$ is a martingale without using Itô's formula

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales

I'm learning the basics about Brownian motion (I know nothing about stochastic calculus), and I've shown that if $W(t)$ is a standard Brownian motion, then $W(t)^2-t$ is a martingale. Now I'm trying to show that 
$$
f(W(t))-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t f''(W(s))ds
$$
is also a martingale, where $f\in C^2$ and compactly supported.

I've started by showing that the transition density satisfies the diffusion equation. Any guidance or hints would be appreciated!

Comment: write the Sde, it won't have a drift term. Therefore, it's expectation is invariant given the current value since the expected change is 0.

Comment: @Ragnar Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately I only know the bare basics about Brownian motion, and nothing about SDEs.

Comment: example with $W(t)^2 - t$,     dW is standard normal with expectation 0 and variance = E[$dW^2$] = dt thus, if g(t,W) =  $W(t)^2 - t$, we use ITO's lemma to get $dg(t,W) = 2W(t)dW$ + ($\frac 12)$2dt$ - $dt$ = $2W(t)dW$, where $E[dg]$ = 0 therefore, $g(W,t)$ = $W(t)^2 - t$ is a martingale.

Comment: @Ragner Thanks again, but unfortunately I do not know Itô's lemma or any stochastic calculus.

Comment: look it up... Standard calculus: let f = f(W(t),t) then, df = $\frac {df}{dW}$(dW) + $\frac {df}{dt}$(dt) + O($dt$). In Ito calculus, the $dW^2$ terms don't go to 0 fast enough since they are basically $dt$. So, we need to include them. In Ito calculus, df = $\frac {df}{dW}$(dW) + $\frac {df}{dt}$(dt) + (1/2)$\frac {d^2f}{dW^2}$($dW^2$) notice how this is the first quadratic term in a taylor expansion (common theme in stochastic calculus). Now, take $dW^2$ = $dt$. And, substitute and collect like terms to get the wikipedia expression. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itō's_lemma

Comment: @theLowerCrust Do you know that the Brownian motion is a Markov process?

Comment: @saz Thanks for the comment. Just learned about them, so I could use them if absolutely necessary? But I definitely know, say, Doob's Upcrossing Lemma, Doob's Maximal Inequality, Fubini's Theorem and the Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote by

$$p(t,x) := \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} \exp \left(- \frac{x^2}{2t} \right), \qquad x \in \mathbb{R},$$

the density of the normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $t$. As you already noted, this function solves the heat equation, i.e.

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} p(t,x) = \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} p(t,x).$$

For $f \in C^2$ compactly supported it follows easily from the integration-by-parts-formula that

$$\int p(t,x) \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} f(x) \, dx = \int f(x) \frac{\partial}{\partial t} p(t,x) \, dx. \tag{1}$$

---

For $f \in C_b^2$ we set $$M_t^f := f(W_t) - f(W_0) - \int_0^t \frac{1}{2} f''(W_r) \, dr.$$ We have to show that $$\mathbb{E}(M_t^f - M_s^f \mid \mathcal{F}_s) = 0 \qquad \text{for all $s \leq t$}.$$ Since $(W_t)_{t \geq 0}$ has independent and stationary increments, we know that $W_t-W_s$ and $\mathcal{F}_s$ are independent and $W_t-W_s \sim W_{t-s}$. Therefore,

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}(M_t^f - M_s^f \mid \mathcal{F}_s) &= \mathbb{E}(f((W_t-W_s)+W_s) \mid \mathcal{F}_s) - f(W_s) \\ &\quad - \frac{1}{2} \int_s^t \mathbb{E}(f''((W_r-W_s)+W_s) \mid \mathcal{F}_s) \, dr \\ &= \mathbb{E} f(W_{t-s}+z) \bigg|_{z=W_s} - f(W_s) - \frac{1}{2} \int_s^t\mathbb{E}[f''(z+(W_r-W_s))] \big|_{z=W_s} \, dr \\ &= \mathbb{E} f(W_{t-s}+z) \bigg|_{z=W_s} - f(W_s) - \frac{1}{2} \int_0^{t-s} \mathbb{E}[f''(z+W_r)] \big|_{z=W_s} \, dr \\ &=  \mathbb{E} \left[ f(z+W_{t-s})-f(z) - \frac{1}{2} \int_0^{t-s} f''(W_r+z) \, dr \right] \bigg|_{z=W_s} \end{align*}$$

(In the last step, we have used that $(W_t)_{t \geq 0}$ has stationary increments, i.e. $W_r-W_s \sim W_{r-s}$, and a change of variables.) Setting $\varphi(x) := f(x+z)$ for fixed $z \in \mathbb{R}$, we therefore conclude that it suffices to show that

$$\mathbb{E}(M_{t-s}^{\varphi} - M_0^{\varphi}) = \mathbb{E} \left[ \varphi(W_{t-s}) - \varphi(0)- \frac{1}{2} \int_0^{t-s} \varphi''(W_r) \, dr \right] = 0. \tag{2}$$

Now fix $0 <\epsilon < u$. Then, by Fubini's theorem ("Fub", for short)

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}(M_u^\varphi-M_\varepsilon^\varphi)  &= \mathbb{E}\left(\varphi(W_u) - \varphi(W_{\varepsilon}) - \frac{1}{2} \int_{\varepsilon}^u \varphi''(W_r) \, dr \right) \\ &\stackrel{\text{Fub}}{=} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \varphi(x) \cdot p(u,x) \, dx - \int_{\mathbb{R}} \varphi(x) \cdot p(\varepsilon,x) \, dx - \frac{1}{2} \int_{\varepsilon}^u \int_{\mathbb{R}} \varphi''(x) \cdot p(r,x) \, dx \, dr \\ &\stackrel{(1)}{=} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \varphi(x) \cdot (p(u,x)-p(\varepsilon,x)) \, dx - \int_{\varepsilon}^u \int_{\mathbb{R}} \varphi(x) \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial r} p(r,x) \, dx \, dr \\ & \overset{\text{Fub}}{\underset{\varepsilon>0}{=}}\int_{\mathbb{R}} \varphi(x) \cdot (p(u,x)-p(\varepsilon,x)) \, dx - \int_{\mathbb{R}} \varphi(x) \cdot \underbrace{\int_{\varepsilon}^u \frac{\partial}{\partial r} p(r,x) \, dr}_{p(u,x)-p(\varepsilon,x)} \, dx \\ &= 0 \tag{3} \end{align*}$$

Since $M_{\epsilon}^{\varphi} \to M_0^{\varphi}$ as $\epsilon \to 0$ (as $f$ is continuous) and $$\|M_{\epsilon}^f\|_{\infty} \leq 2 \|f\|_{\infty} + u \|f''\|_{\infty}, \qquad 0 < \epsilon < u$$ it follows from the dominated convergence theorem that we can let $\epsilon \to 0$ and obtain

$$0 \stackrel{(3)}{=} \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \mathbb{E}(M_u^\varphi-M_\varepsilon^\varphi) = \mathbb{E}(M_u^\varphi-M_0^\varphi).$$

This proves $(2)$.

**Remark:** This answer follows the proof presented by René Schilling and Lothar Partzsch in *Brownian Motion - An Introduction to Stochastic Processes*, Chapter 5.

Comment: @theLowerCrust Upcrossing estimate is Lemma A.5, not Lemma A.3. Lemma A.3 states states that $$\mathbb{E}(f(X,Y) \mid \mathcal{F}) = \mathbb{E}f(X,y) \big|_{y=Y}$$ if $Y$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable and $X$ independent from $\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you!

Comment: @theLowerCrust You are welcome.